# How to remove spacing Text is adding in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, text, android-jetpack-compose, padding

I'm trying to make a bar graph, that has labels on some of them. [Image of the bar as is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtAMv.png).
The labels below each vertical bar is adding unwanted spacing between the bars.
I would like the remove that extra spacing between each bar, but I don't know how.
I made the bars with Jetpack Compose, like this (I removed most of the code. It isn't necessary to show in this case):

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(8.dp)
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
        )

    }
    vText(
        text = "21",
        modifier = Modifier,
    )
}
```

I added the bars in a Row().

I need a solution as to how I can make the space between each bar the same, but still be able to show the labels. I tried SpaceEvenly in the Row(), but that just cuts off the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I edited the `Text()` to include the modifier `.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true)`.

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeyQJ.png)